# EmberJS: Render default template

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I am trying to build an Ember Application which I want to render a default template of the nested route into the index route. Here is the `router.js`

```
export default Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('featured');
    this.route('authors');
    this.route('popular');
  });
});
```

Here is the `posts-index.hbs` template:

```
<div class="posts">
  <h2>Welcome to your blog posts</h2>
  <p>Here are your posts:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>{{#link-to 'posts.featured'}}Featured{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to 'posts.authors'}}Authors{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to 'posts.popular'}}Popular{{/link-to}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="posts-container">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the `posts-index/featured.hbs` template:

```
<div class="featured-posts">
  <h3>List of featured posts</h3>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Other templates are the same as the `featured` template.

As you can see in the application above, I want when user visits the `/posts`, they will see the `posts-index` template, as well as the `posts/featured.hbs` template being rendered as default. Of course, user can still navigate to url `/posts/featured`, and seeing the same content.

Any suggestions to this are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember `Route` provides a [`renderTemplate`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/rendering-a-template/) hook which you can use like this:

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({

  renderTemplate: function() {
    // renders the template for the current route, as per conventions
    // in your case it will be 'posts/index' 
    this.render();

    // renders the named template 'posts/feature' *into* another named template
    this.render('posts/featured', {
      into: 'posts/index' // which in this case is 'posts/index'
    }); 
  }
});
```

(see [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/suwevujiga/1/edit?html,js,output))

Comment: Thank you for the quick tip. Here is what I really want to accomplished. http://jsbin.com/feduresotu/1/edit